# Determine the variance of $X$ given the probabilty distributive function $f(x) = (1-x^2)$ for $0\le x\le 2$.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

I tried to solve the same using $E(x^2)-[E(x)]^2$, but the answers I found come out to be negative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Comment: Probability distribution functions are not negetive.

Comment: $f$ is not a density function on $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is not a valid probability density function - one requirement is that for any event $E$, $P(E)\in[0,1]$. However, $P(1.5)<0$ for example and so the question is impossible.

Comment: lol very funny...+1

Comment: How so? Thanks tho:))

Comment: cause i never see this in classes but here sometimes people post things that dont "work"

Comment: this question been coming in my uni exam from past two years

Comment: I suspect the correct answer for that in an exam would be to say that the function provided does not satisfy the Kolmogorov Axioms for a probability density function, and therefore we cannot calculate the variance. Further, even if you don't notice this, a negative variance is impossible so you can arrive at the same conclusion that way.

Comment: So even the standard deviation calculated using that variance will be erratic?

Comment: Indeed, notice that $\sigma=(Var(X))^\frac{1}{2}$ and the square root of a negative number is complex.